# How to find sum of other categories in the data in R?

Tags: r, group-by, sum, dplyr, panel-data

I have a panel data, sampled monthly for various product types.

```
type year month cost 
 A   2020  01     3
 A   2020  02     6
 B   2020  01     7
 B   2020  02     9
 C   2020  01     10
 C   2020  02     15
```

I need to calculate an additional variable stating: "For a given period, what is the sum of costs from other product types?"

For example,

- For 2020-01, Total Cost = 3 + 7 + 10 = 20. Costs of non-A types are 20 - 3 = 17.
- For 2020-02, Total Cost = 6 + 9 + 15 = 30. Costs of non-B types are 30 - 9 = 21.

So the final data frame should look like this:

```
type year month cost other_costs
 A   2020  01     3      17
 A   2020  02     6      24
 B   2020  01     7      13
 B   2020  02     9      21
 C   2020  01     10     10
 C   2020  02     15     15
```

I have tried group_by() + mutate() functions from dplyr, but I get NA with the following code:

```
df %>%
 group_by(year, month) %>%
 mutate(other_costs = sum(cost) - cost)
```

What are your suggestions?

Comment: Your code works fine on the sample dataset. You might want to add `sum(cost, na.rm=TRUE)` in case you have NAs in your dataset